# How do I add an article to WordPress by using the elementor plugin widgets?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

please provide the steps to add an article using Elementor widgets.

1. Installed the elementor plugin
2. I see the elementor menu item
3. I am logged in as admin
4. I added a page and then clicked edit with elementor

I need to post an article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take for example the header block from the left side and drag and drop it onto your page. The headline now appears and can be edited there. 
You can do the same with texts and other premade elements.

Comment: how do I an article?  Are you saying an article is a widget to be drag and dropped and edited?